# How to add simple many2one field in existing module on ODOO 8?

Tags: python, customization, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to create a simple many2one field in ODOO 8, in crm.lead view

This is my code:

campo_regione.py

```
from openerp import models, fields, osv
class nome_regione(models.Model):
  _name = "nome_regione"
  _inherit = "crm.lead"
  name = fields.Char('Nome', size=20, required=True)
class campo_regione(models.Model):
  _name = "campo_regione"
  _inherit = "crm.lead"
  _description = "Regione"
  campo_regione_id = fields.Many2one('nome_regione', 'Nome Regione')
```

campo_regione.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
   <data>
      <record model = "ir.ui.view" id = "campo_regione">
         <field name ="name">crm.regione.inherit</field>
         <field name = "model">crm.lead</field>
         <field name = "inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_leads"></field>
         <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='country_id']" position="after">
                <field name="campo_regione_id">Regione</field>
            </xpath>
        </field>
      </record>
   </data>
</openerp>
```

Now, after the module installs, odoo stops responding, even if I restart it, it goes on loop.

I'm able to login only by renaming or deleting the new module.

What am I wrong? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed few things into your code just try following.

```
from openerp import models, fields
class nome_regione(models.Model):
  _name = "nome_regione"
  name = fields.Char('Nome', size=20, required=True)
class campo_regione(models.Model):
  _inherit = "crm.lead"
  _description = "Regione"
  campo_regione_id = fields.Many2one('nome_regione', 'Nome Regione')
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! Now I would like to share the same field with the partner module, to not lost the field data after Leads conversion. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you please clear your requirement bit more, so I can help you.

Comment: In the CRM module there is a relation between lead and partner, a lead can be converted to partner by clicking the button "convert to Oppportunity". I need that this field in the lead module will be visible even on partner module, so that after the conversion I not loose the field in partner module.

Comment: Leads & Opportunities are of same model crm.lead you can get this field in both.

Comment: If your aim is differ then please clarify such code with the issues so that we can reach up to the conclusion.

Comment: This field it's part of the address, so I need that after the conversion it goes on the field "Regione" on the Company address, in object res.partner.

Answer (score 1):

When a model is changed (add, remove, rename, whatever..) you MUST restart service.

```
sudo service odoo restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to add custom field to `crm.lead`

```
class Lead(models.Model):
_inherits = 'crm.lead'

x_facturation = fields.Boolean("x_facturation", default=False)

<record model="ir.ui.view" id="devis_form_view">
  <field name="name">lead.facturation</field>
  <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
  <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_form_view_oppor"/>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <notebook position="inside">
      <page string="Factures">
        <group>
          <field name="x_facturation"/>                         
        </group>
      </page>
    </notebook>
  </field>
</record>
```

But I got error while installing : Field x_facturation does not exist When I try with else model (ex : res.partner) it work fine